# Why I get this POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found) when posting front to back?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I was trying to post data from frontend to backend server. But I have these 2 error found:

1. POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)
2. error Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
   And literally have no idea... please help me!!!

Here is my folder structure:
[image]

The sendmail is the backend part, its folder is inside the react frontend.

And the frontend code for posting data is:

```
    const [subscribeEmail, setSubscribeEmail] = useState()
    console.log(subscribeEmail)
    const handleOk = async () => {
        await fetch('http://localhost:3001/', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: subscribeEmail
            })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => JSON.parse(data))
            .catch(err => console.log('error', err.message))

        setModal(false)
    }

    return (
         <h3 onClick={() => setModal(true)}>Sign up for our daily insider!  Click me to do so! </h3>
                    <Modal
                        title="Thanks for subscribe our daily insider!"
                        style={{
                            top: 20,
                        }}
                        open={modal}
                        centered
                        onOk={handleOk}
                        onCancel={() => setModal(false)}
                    >
                        <p>Tell us your email here:</p>
                        <Input onChange={(e) => { setSubscribeEmail(e.target.value) }} />
                    </Modal>
     )
```

Then is the code of backend:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// const https = require('https')
const cors = require('cors')
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')

sgMail.setApiKey('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')

const app = express()
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    })
)
app.use(cors)
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email
    console.log(email)
})

app.listen(3001, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log('listen error', err)
    console.log('successfully connected')
})
```

The error is catched in the frontend code.

Please help me! So grateful!

Comment: Are you getting this console.log(email) in the back end?

Comment: Yeah I wanted to get the email from the frontend. And use the eamil at the backend @yousoumar

Comment: I see. I was asking, are getting this log `console.log(email)` in the backend?

Comment: Yes I wanna let this log in the server.js the backend

Comment: Oh, btw, I just changed the port that `app.listen()` and in the fetch. I changed them to `http://localhost:3001/` because I realized I would use the same port as the react. And the folder structure, but that seems ok

Comment: After this, it doesn't show any errors but won't log at the backend

Comment: Response.json() already yields a valid json object, no need to parse it. Additionally you are not sending anything back to the client. When you are using react and want a backend system as well I recommend you to use the next.js framework! :)